# Стилизация компонента EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Хочу в компонент `EditText` вставить иконку с левого края, и закруглить немного углы, а так же изменить цвет и толщину рамки.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию, в поисковиках не чего не удалось найти.

Comment: под толщиной обводки что вы понимаете?

Comment: и какая тема используется в вашем приложении?

Comment: Вам нужно сделать свой background drawable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17449486/872294

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для кастомизации внешнего вида EditText, вам надо будет создать drawable (описав его в XML), а затем поставить его на background.

Вам следует разобраться в тэгах XML для создания drawable. Тогда вы сможете привести ваш элемент к нужному именно вам внешнему виду. Мой пример делает у EditText скруглённые углы, белую заливку фона и чёрную границу.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Shape отвечает за форму элемента, solid - за заливку, stroke - за границу, corners описывает углы.

Иконка добавляется в EditText и того проще:

```
<EditText
    ...  
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon" />
```

Comment: Вот здесь есть, как воспользоваться данным решением: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577887/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%83-layout-%D0%B2-androidstudio