# Закруглить углы у layout в AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-layout

В главном меню по кнопке вызывается новый `layout`, через `DmMetrics` сжимаем размер слоя на полэкрана.

Как сделать его углы круглыми?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

попробуйте такой вариант

Создаете стиль для `LinerLayout` в файле `krugliye_ugli.xml` в папке `drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <corners android:radius="8dp" />
  <padding
    android:top="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:right="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Потом его передаете на `LinerLayout` в виде

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.krugliye_ugli);
```